# How to use log4j write logs into a mysql database on Jmeter?

Tags: log4j, jmeter

Jmeter default write logs into a file named "jmeter.log".But there is a file named "log4j.conf" under the folder "bin". I confused about how to use it. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check in the conf

```
# JMeter does not use log4j as logging system
# This configuration will only be used by libraries that do use log4j
# or your custom code if it uses it
# For logging configuration of JMeter, it needs to be done in user.properties
```

how it works.

If you have special sampler that uses java code .. in that java code if you use log.info , log.error, log.warn statements it prints that to jmeter.log   Hope this helps

If you have jsr223 groovy sampler try putting below line and check jmeter.log you see the logging info.

```
log.info "check this in jmeter.log"
```

Hope this helps ..

Comment: tks. I just use java code complete it. I didn't use the "log4j.conf". I think this file is not usefull for users.

Comment: It helps for those people who write extensive jmeter plugins and JSR code segments to debug , this is where it is useful .if that helps please click answered.